# C++ error: invalid types '<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]'

Tags: c++, error-handling

So I completely rewrote my code from previous entry, and Im trying to use vectors to get the job done this time. However upon using square brackets I get an error, when changing them to normal brackets or parentheses '(' ')', my first line executes, but upon writing your list it gives an error of

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 4) >= this->size() (which is 4)

EDIT: I am attempting to write a code that takes ones input for the number of elements, following the elements themselves, to bubble sort, with  error handling.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cctype>
#include<stdexcept>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,j,temp,numElements;
    cout << "Please enter the number of elements:";

 try 
 {
    cin >> numElements;
    vector<int> userInput(numElements);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the list to be sorted:"; 
    cout << endl;

    for(i = 0;i < userInput.size(); ++i)
    {
        cin >> userInput.at(i);
        if (cin.fail()) 
        {
          throw runtime_error("invalid input");
        }
    }
    for(i = 0;i < userInput.size(); ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0;j < (userInput.size() - i); ++j)
            if(userInput.at[j] > userInput.at [j + 1])
            {
                temp = userInput.at[j];
                userInput.at[j] = userInput.at[j+1];
                userInput.at[j+1] = temp;
            }
    }

  cout<<"The sorted list is:";
  for(i = 0; i < userInput.size(); ++i)
  cout<<" "<< userInput[i];

  }
  catch (runtime_error& excpt)
  {
    cout << "error: " << excpt.what() << endl;
  }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so what is the question here? Is this homework? it seems to me all you need to do is read what the exception thrown means.

Comment: I am attempting to write a code that takes ones input for the number of elements, following the elements themselves, to bubble sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. One is the use of array subscript `[]` for `at`. You have to change it
   to `()`.
2. In the below statements in the code, you end up accessing an out of bounds memory because `j` goes upto `userInput.size()` when `i`
   is 0. And this is what causes the exception.

`if(userInput.at[j] > userInput.at [j + 1])`

`userInput.at[j] = userInput.at[j+1];`

`userInput.at[j+1] = temp;`

The solution for this is to change the inner `for` loop to:

```
for(j = 0;j < (userInput.size() - i - 1); ++j)
```

Output:

```
Please enter the number of elements:4

Enter the list to be sorted:
98 78 56 23   
The sorted list is: 23 56 78 98
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot mix and match braces, you can either use [`std::vector::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at)

```
userInput.at(j)    // ok
```

or [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)

```
userInput[j]       // ok
```

but not both

```
userInput.at[j]    // wrong
```